# Structure and oxidation state of bridging complexes

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, coordination-compounds, oxidation-state

I am confused about the structure of bridging complexes with the bridging ligands as $\ce{OH-}$ or $\ce{NH2-}.$ Aren't they both monodentate ligands?

And if they form a simple coordinate bond, then the negative charge on them must be lost, but then the oxidation states of the metal atoms doesn't match. For example:

[image: Tetraaquaplatinum(IV)-μ-amido-μ-hydro-tetraammineplatinum(IV)]

In this compound, please explain what bonds $\ce{OH}$ and $\ce{NH2}$ are actually forming, and the charges on them. Also, how do we find the oxidation state of platinum?

Comment: The typical way of dealing with these is to treat it as an X ligand for one metal and an L ligand for the other. You should alternate so that each metal see one L and one X ligand in the bis-bridged case.